# Observable in java is null

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

Ca someone explain to me why I get a null pointer exception ?

```
private Observer obs1;
private Observer obs2;
public void notifyObservers(Observable observable) {
        String str1 = "Observer 1 :\n";
        String str2 = "Observer 2 :\n";

        try {
            Student[] studList = returnStudents();
            for (int i=0;i<returnStudents().length;i++) {
                if(studList[i].computeAverage() >= 5)
                    str1 = str1 + studList[i].toString() + "\n";
                else
                    str2 = str2 + studList[i].toString() + "\n";

            }
        } catch (MyException ex) {
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
        }
        obs1.update(observable, str1);
        obs2.update(observable, str2);
    }
```

And my Observer class:

```
public class Watcher implements Observer {

    public void update(Observable arg0, Object arg1) {
        System.out.println("The list of students has changed");
        System.out.println(arg1);

    }

}
```

I will explain a little wwhat is happening here. I have made a program that manages a list of students.I can add/delete a students.
After each add I call

```
setChanged();
notifyObservers(this);
```

Here I want that observer1 to show the studens with a average of grades > 5 and observer2 to show the ones with average < 5.
I'm getting a null pointer exception in here: `obs1.update(observable, str1);`
I must say that I tried to print `str1` and `str2` and they contain the list of students. So my guess is that the problem is at `observable`

Comment: Where are you assigning values to `obs1` and `obs2` ? They seem to be null so NPE.

Comment: Add the `final` modifier to variables and some questions will never have to be asked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see you assigning a value to `obs1` or `obs2` anywhere. When a variable isn't assigned a value, it is "null".

Comment: What shoul I assign to these values so that it won't affect later? Some kind of initialization but with what?

Comment: `obs1 = new Watcher()` `obs2 = new Watcher()`